# Given a subset of numbers $1, \dots, n$, find the minimal subset of numbers $1, \dots, n$ sums of every subset of which cover all sums of first subset

Tags: algorithms, np-hard, subset-sum

Given a subset $A = \{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k\}$ of numbers $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, find another subset $B = \{b_1, b_2, \dots, b_t\}$ of numbers $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ of minimal size (that is, minimise $t$), that every sum of subset of $A$ can be acquired as a sum of some subset of $B$, in time $O\left(2^{\log^2 n}\right)$.

My first observation was what $B$ is indeed the subset (if some number $x$ occurs twice in $B$, we can only optimise the answer if we replace the second occurrence with $2x$).

Also, maximal answer is of size at most $\log n + 1$, as maximal sum is of order $n^2$ and therefore contains $\log n + 1$ bits in binary, which gives the naive answer $-$ just use powers of $2$ from $0$ to $\log n$, all sums of subsets of $A$ can be easily acquired now.

That said, $O\left(2^{\log^2 n}\right) = O\left(\left(2^{\log n}\right)^{\log n}\right)$, seems like it's some bruteforce of subsets of $A$, but I struggle to come up with something.

Comment: when you say "if some number occurs twice", you suggest you can have twice the same value in a subset of {1, 2, ..., n} ? Can you also please correct the title which contains twice the word "find" and finally means nothing ?